# Динамически получить доступ к классу Resources

Tags: c#, dll, resources

Не получается получить доступ к классу `Resources` DLL динамически. Обычный способ получения функций `Activator.CreateInstance(type)` не работает из-за ошибки.

Файл Resources из DLL. Нужно в `Form` получить метод `hero3`, который появился при добавлении картинки, и вывести ее в `Form`.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Этот код создан программой.
//     Исполняемая версия:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Изменения в этом файле могут привести к неправильной работе и будут потеряны в случае
//     повторной генерации кода.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace mydll.Properties {
    using System;


    /// <summary>
    ///   Класс ресурса со строгой типизацией для поиска локализованных строк и т.д.
    /// </summary>
    // Этот класс создан автоматически классом StronglyTypedResourceBuilder
    // с помощью такого средства, как ResGen или Visual Studio.
    // Чтобы добавить или удалить член, измените файл .ResX и снова запустите ResGen
    // с параметром /str или перестройте свой проект VS.
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "15.0.0.0")]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    public class Resources {

        private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;

        private static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo resourceCulture;

        [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
        internal Resources() {
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Возвращает кэшированный экземпляр ResourceManager, использованный этим классом.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        public static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
            get {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                    global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("mydll.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
                    resourceMan = temp;
                }
                return resourceMan;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Перезаписывает свойство CurrentUICulture текущего потока для всех
        ///   обращений к ресурсу с помощью этого класса ресурса со строгой типизацией.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        public static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
            get {
                return resourceCulture;
            }
            set {
                resourceCulture = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Поиск локализованного ресурса типа System.Drawing.Bitmap.
        /// </summary>
        public static System.Drawing.Bitmap hero3 {
            get {
                object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("hero3", resourceCulture);
                return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activator.CreateInstance не нужен, так как свойство статическое. Сделайте как-то так:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

// ...          

Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom("путь к DLL");
TypeInfo t = ass.DefinedTypes.Where((x) => (x.Name == "Resources")).First();
PropertyInfo prop = t.DeclaredProperties.Where((x) => (x.Name == "hero3")).First();
var bitmap = (System.Drawing.Bitmap) prop.GetMethod.Invoke(null,new object[] { });
```

Comment: Супер, все работает. Что делает `.First()`?

Comment: @AntonKiverchuk Возвращает первый элемент из последовательности. Метод Where возвращает последовательность (так как лямбде-условию в общем случае могут соответствовать несколько объектов). Так как в нашем случае нужен один объект, мы вызываем First.